# How to prevent/avoid of script execution during work of js interpreter

Tags: javascript

example of js file that will be parsed during loading:

```
var Test = {
   someProp: Utils.getProp()
}
var Utils = {
   myAttr: "",

   getProp: function() { 
      alert("Test"); 
   }
}
```

The error that I'm getting during page loading is

```
"TypeError: Utils is undefined"
```

As far as I understand js interpreter is executing script during page load and in such case the error is occuring. The question here: is it real to load the page and to avoid the script execution? or how can I avoid the error?

Comment: Move the initialization of "Utils" so that it's before "Test".

Comment: "how can I avoid the error?" - don't try and use variables before they are declared/available.

Comment: `getProp` does not actually return anything?

Comment: Nope. It is just example. Sorry for bad naming

Answer (score 2):

Since `Test` depends on `Utils`, `Utils` must be defined first.

```
var Utils = {
   myAttr: "",

   getProp: function() { 
      alert("Test"); 
   }
} 
var Test = {
   someProp: Utils.getProp()
}
```

Comment: It will not help. Before posting the message I've checked this variant as well. But it did not help, because objects will be created after js interpreter parses the all scripts. Quick solution here is to wrap the Utils.getProp() into function: like function getProp() { Utils.getProp(); }